# Add a SQL Query after another one

Tags: php, sql

Okey so I'm gonna try and after I get the right password and crosscheck fetch the users information from a table. How can I run this right after this.

```
$sql = "select password from users where name = '" . $_POST['name'] . "' and password='" . $_POST['pass'] . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "succesful";
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $_session['sessionid'] = id();
        //
        //Im gonna do a sql query here!
        //
        echo '<h1 style="text-align: center;">Logged in!</h1>';
        $_SESSION['user']= $_POST['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

First up it's VERY dangerous to just use $_POST['name'] in your queries, you should clean it first. You can use mysql_real_escape_string() [although this might be deprecated]. Have a look at prepared statements too, that can also help. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

to answer your actual question. You should be returning the ID of the user from the first query and not the password. Then you can use the ID and pull out the user information within that logic block.

Comment: But i dont want the ID, i want to insert a new session ID.

Comment: You literally wrote: " fetch the users information from a table" you cant do that with just the password. Looks like you havent actually asked the correct question at all